# Hover effect that changes all of same type except selected hover

Tags: css

I am trying to do a hover effect that changes other "a" tags along with the hovered "a" tag. So far I can only do the selected hover.

```css
ul li{
  list-style: none;
}
ul li a {
   color: black;
}
ul li a:hover{
   color: green;
   background: orange;
}
ul li a:hover:not(a:hover){
   color: red;
   background: black;
 }
```

```html
  <ul>
   <li>
     <a>test</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a>test</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a>test</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

In essense, I'd like the selected hover to be color green and background orange and then the other "a" tags to have color red and background black;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you set a hover rule at the `ul` level that changes all items to black and red, and then override it on the specific hovered item?

```css
ul li{
  list-style: none;
}

ul:hover li a {
   color: red;
   background: black;
}

ul li a {
   color: black;
}

ul li a:hover{
   color: green;
   background: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
     <a>test</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a>test</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a>test</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Yes that works thanks!